# How to convert a string containing control characters to a string with the control characters applied?

Tags: python

I need to get the following string as if it were printed using `print()`

```py
str = '1234\b\b\b\b\r5678\n'
```

I want to apply the backspace characters ('\b','\r' and etc), for an output (str2) line of the form:

```
str2 = '5678\n'
```

And another example:

```py
str = '1234\b\r5678\nqwert\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\r1234'
```

Result:

```py
str = '5678\n1234'
```

Comment: Sorry to write in Russian.

Comment: The second example's output doesn't match the locations of the backspaces. I think the output would be `12356123`

Comment: @Haem, No, output: '5678\n'
Try it:
str = '1234\b\b\b\b\r5678\n'
print(str)

Comment: I see. I didn't realize that `\r`  returns the cursor to the start of the current line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply control characters to a string - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36576216/apply-control-characters-to-a-string-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take care of at least \b and \r but it is not a generic solution for any control sequence that you could encounter

```
import re

def convert_to_term(str):
    """
    coverts \b (\x08) and \r as a printout to terminal would represent it
    """
    # \b backspace
    str = re.sub(r'.\x08', '', str)
    # \r carriage return
    str = re.sub(r'(^|\n)[^\n]+\r', r'\1', str)
    return str

in_str = '1234 \b \b \b \b \r5678 \n'
out_str = convert_to_term(in_str)
print ("\"" + out_str + "\"")
print (len(out_str))

in_str = '1234\b\r5678\nqwert\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\r1234'
out_str = convert_to_term(in_str)
print ("\"" + out_str + "\"")
print (len(out_str))
```

gives:

```
"5678 
"
6
"5678
1234"
9
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for the case: given_string='1234\b\r5678\nqwert\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\r1234' The result should be: new_string='5678\n1234'

Comment: for me it works (after changing  convert_to_term(str) to  convert_to_term(in_str)) I get a 9 character string that looks just like 5678\n1234

Answer (score -1):

*In  python*

```
 import re
 re.sub(r"[a-zA-z]","",re.sub(r"[^\w\n]","", '1234\b\r5678\nqwert\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\r1234'))
```

*In javascript*

```
"1234\b\r5678\nqwert\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\r1234".replace(/[^\w\n]/gi,"").replace(/[a-z]/gi,"")
```

Comment: Code has been Edited now its Returning With ''\n"

Answer (score -2):

```
def apply_controls(string):
    pointer = 0
    output = []
    line_pointer = 0

    for character in string:
        #handles the alphanumeric characters
        if character.isalnum():
            output[pointer:pointer+1] = character
            pointer += 1
        #only does backspace if there are any characters on current line
        elif character == "\b":
            if pointer > line_pointer:
                output[pointer:pointer+1] = ''
                pointer -= 1
        #retains the new line and updates the line_pointer
        elif character == "\n":
            output[pointer:pointer+1] = character
            pointer += 1
            line_pointer = pointer
        #deletes all characters on the given line
        elif character == "\r":
            output[line_pointer:pointer+1] = ''
            pointer = line_pointer
        else:
            print("Unknown character: "+character)

    return "".join(output)
```

This does give the output you desire.

Comment: Will that code apply the backspace characters, or just remove them? Also, the regex as written will remove spaces, like the newline that's supposed to stay in the end.

Comment: if input is `"abcc\bdef"` your current code will output `"def"` instead of the expected `"abcdef"`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for the case: given_string='1234\b\r5678\nqwert\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\r1234'
The result should be: new_string='5678\n1234'

Comment: @ПашаКашин: Try the new function and let me know if it works as desired.